# How to iterate over the rows from 2 files, compare the values and update the value in a file when the condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

For changing the values from 10 to 18, 19 or 20, I am splitting the string, access the substrings and then trying to change it. Its working but just not changing the values. Here is the solution I am trying to implement:

```
oldFileName = 'tryout.hmo'
newFileName = 'tryout_NEW.hmo'
topoFileName = 'Density.topo'

readme = open( oldFileName, "r" )
oldLines = readme.readlines()       

readme = open(topoFileName, "r")
Lines = readme.readlines()
readme.close()

newFile = open(newFileName,"w")


for row in oldLines:
    for line in Lines:
        tmp = line.split()
    list =  row.rstrip()
    tmp1 = list.split()
    newFile.write(row)
    if row.find("BEG_ELEM_DATA") > -1:
       if tmp[0] == tmp1[0]:
           if tmp[2] == 1 and tmp[3] == 0:
            # it is magnet, value 18
             newFile.write(tmp1.replace(tmp1[1], "18"))
         
           elif tmp[2] == 1 and tmp[3] == 1:               
              # it is iron, value 19
             newFile.write(tmp1.replace(tmp1[1], "19"))
         
           else:
            # it is air, value 20
             newFile.write(tmp1.replace(tmp1[1], "20")) 

newFile.close()
```

I would really appreciate it if you could able to solve this problem in above script, then I guess it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is the solution you were searching for.

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_csv('Density.topo', header = 0, names = list('ABCD'), delimiter=r'\s+', skiprows=1)
df2[['C', 'D']]= df2[['C', 'D']].round()

new_file_content=''

with open('tryout.hmo', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

        if line[11:13] == '10':

            if line[3].isspace():
                ID_to_search_for = line[4:8] # number with 4 digits
            else:
                ID_to_search_for = line[3:8] # number with 5 digits
            search_idx = df2[df2['A'] == ID_to_search_for].index[0]

            if df2['C'][search_idx] == 1 and df2['D'][search_idx] == 0:
                change = '18' #magnet
                new_line = line[:11] + change + line[13:]
            elif df2['C'][search_idx] == 1 and df2['D'][search_idx] == 1:
                change = '19' #iron
                new_line = line[:11] + change + line[13:]
            else:
                change = '20' #air
                new_line = line[:11] + change + line[13:]

            new_file_content += new_line

        else:
            new_file_content += line
    
with open('tryout_changed.hmo', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_file_content)
```

if you don't want to use dataframes, you can do it like this:

```
with open('density.topo') as f:
    lists_of_list = [line.rstrip().split() for line in f]

new_file_content=''
with open('tryout_test.hmo', 'r') as f:
    
    for line in f:
        
        if line[11:13] == '10':
            if line[3].isspace():
                ID_to_search_for = line[4:8] # number with 4 digits
            else:
                ID_to_search_for = line[3:8] # number with 5 digits
            for idx, sublist in enumerate(lists_of_list):
                if sublist[0] == ID_to_search_for:                    
                    if lists_of_list[idx][2] == 1 and lists_of_list[idx][3] == 0:
                        change = '18' #magnet
                        new_line = line[:11] + change + line[13:]
                    elif lists_of_list[idx][2] == 1 and lists_of_list[idx][3] == 1:
                        change = '19' #iron
                        new_line = line[:11] + change + line[13:]
                    else:
                        change = '20' #air
                        new_line = line[:11] + change + line[13:]

                    new_file_content += new_line

        else:
            new_file_content += line
    
with open('tryout_changed.hmo', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_file_content)
```

ok, here is my final answer. It does (again) all things you were searching for. Please debug your code in your IDE if there is a problem. You should start using context manager instead of open and closing files step by step.
I wrote the new code around your code in the question and added some comments to it.

```
oldFileName = 'tryout.hmo'
newFileName = 'tryout_NEW.hmo'
topoFileName = 'Density.topo'

readme = open( oldFileName, "r" )
oldLines = readme.readlines()

m = int(oldLines[3])
print(m)
new_m = m+3
m1 = str(m)
new_m1 = str(new_m)

Phrase = "END_COMP_DATA"
#n = "Phrase not found" #not used --> not needed

with open(oldFileName,"r") as oldFile: 
    for number, lin in enumerate(oldFile):
        if Phrase in lin:
          n = number
       
#insert 3 lines to tryout_new at the right position (--> row n)
magnet = f"      {m+1} "'"                     topo_magnet"'"\n" 
iron   = f"      {m+2} "'"                       topo_iron"'"\n" 
air    = f"      {m+3} "'"                        topo_air"'"\n"  
    
oldLines[n:n] = [magnet, iron, air]

newFile = open(newFileName,"w") 
flag = 0

with open('density.topo') as f:
    data_density = [line.rstrip().split() for line in f]

for idx, row in enumerate(oldLines):
    lst =  row.rstrip() #I think you shouldn't name a variable like a class in python (list). use 'lst' or something like that
    tmp_tryout = lst.split()
    if row.find("BEG_ELEM_DATA") > -1:
        flag = 1
    if flag == 1 and len(tmp_tryout)>1:
        # if the column has more than 2 columns (after split), check for the "10"
        if tmp_tryout[1] == '10':
            # density_idx_line searchs in density.topo for a match with tmp_tryout[0] (e.g. 3749) and stores the whole line
            density_idx_line = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == tmp_tryout[0], data_density))
            if len(density_idx_line) >0:
                if density_idx_line[0][2] == '1.0' and density_idx_line[0][3] == '1e-05':
                    # the ' 10 ' is the 10 with a whitespace before and after it. Only like this only the 10 gets replaced (and not e.g. 3104 to 3184)    
                    newFile.write(row.replace(' 10 ', ' 18 '))       
                elif density_idx_line[0][2] == '1.0' and density_idx_line[0][3] == '1.0':               

                    newFile.write(row.replace(' 10 ', ' 19 ')) 
                else:

                    newFile.write(row.replace(' 10 ', ' 20 '))
        else: 
            newFile.write(row)
    else: 
        if idx == 3: 
            newFile.write(row.replace(m1, new_m1)) 
        else:
            newFile.write(row)       
                
newFile.close()
print ("script terminated successfully!")
```

Comment: This code will work but only for this particular files not for other files, most likely I am searching solutions in python without using dataframes. I tried one solution in python, its almost working but not updating the values, I will tag you there.

Comment: What do you mean with other files? The format of this file is quite messy, so ye I just coded it for this special file. If you want to have it more in general you could use regular expressions to find the different "columns" between all these whitespaces which change all the time. Without using the dataframe should also not be a big problem, just a different way to compare values in the second file (because for me the more difficult problem was to find and change the values in the tryout file). Yes, I would appreciate if you let me know what your final solution looks like.

Comment: Yes, I am also facing the same problem with change the values in the tryout file. I will edit my question and put the code in my question above. I would appreciate if you can find the soultion to this, then it can be used for all other text files.

Comment: I have added the code in the answer solution section not in question. Please do check it above. Also, in code without using dataframes only changing values from 10 to 20 everywhere.

Comment: I will try my best. I'll see and debug your script in the answer. What IDE do you use, or where do you write your code? Why didnt you use my suggestion? If everywhere is 20 then the if/elif condition is never right. You can also debug my code at your place why it isn't working.... for me it works.

Comment: Your code is really confusing me. I think there are several steps which are just useless. You write lines to a NewFile then in the next loop you just create the same file again and overwrite it. Why writing it in the first place? for your first problem (inserting instead of replacing), here a possible way: `magnet = "      18 "'"                      topo_magnet"'"\n"
iron = "      19 "'"                      topo_iron"'"\n"
air = "      20 "'"                      topo_air"'"\n"

oldLines[n:n] = [magnet, iron, air]`

Comment: can you please check your code in your answer again? I think the intendation level is messed up due to copy paste.

Comment: I am using spyder to write my code. I have added your suggestion of inserting magnet, iron and air--its working and also corrected the indentation. Now the code after readme = open(topoFileName, "r") is important as I have added flag = 0 and 1, so its looping through the file, able to find line "BEG_ELEM_DATA", but just not able to update the value, am I using the correct replace method for tmp1 and also float numbers such as 1.0 and 1e-05 are identifiable right?

Comment: As suggested by Review team, I have added the code in my original question above, @Rabinzel please check it above. Also corrected the indentation.

Comment: intendation level is still wrong at several places. I will go and debug your script now. You should google how to debug in spyder, set some breakpoints, then you can see if for example 1.0 and 1e-5 are identified or not.

Comment: I edited line by line and now indentation level is completely ok. I am not sure, but problem with not updating values is writing the new file because in the code I am writing rows of tryout file using newFile.write(row) and replacing tmp1[1] in tmp1 by using newFile.write(tmp1.replace(tmp1[1], "18")). in write method, I cannot use list as in tmp1.

Comment: that is what I was telling you. If you want to keep the exactly format of the original file you can't split every row to list, because after writing it again in the new file, it doesn't have the same whitespaces anymore. That is why I used this syntax `new_line = line[:11] + change + line[13:]` . I found another problem in your code: "for row in oldLines: for line in Lines:" for every row of tryout file (70733 rows) you loop through the whole density file (7009rows) thats why code is slow AND it is wrong because everytime you hit the if/else statements, your is tmp = "$END EDYSON" (last row)

Comment: Ok. After adding the code for inserting lines into your without using dataframes code, the result I am getting is 3749   20 106    10690    10692    10693    10695    10658    10689, 20 instead of 18 which means if and elif statements are not working is it beacuse I used 1.0 instead of 1 and 1e-05 instead of 0. Do you know the reason for that?

Comment: try to change 1.0 to '1.0' and and 1e-05 to '1e-05' . I think then it should work

Comment: Ok. I did not understand this line line[:11] + change + line[13:]? or line[3] ? Because for other file if I need to change the different factor instead of 10 say for example change 7 then how will it work?

Comment: ye this is very specific. i looked up the original format of the .hmo file. this code just takes everything from the start of the row (-> line[:11] ), then the value i want to change, and then everything till the end of the row (-> line[13:] ). This only works if you want to change the number which has 2 digits at position 11&12 in your string. with the + you can combine strings back to back. Doing it like this maintains the format of your original file.

Comment: what you mean by start of the row as in what is 11 or 13, not understanding what you are saying? also 11 and 12 position. Can you tell me exactly what lines or strings in the original script are you referring to ?

Comment: your variable oldLines from the original tryout.hmo file is a list with every row of the file. every row is saved as one big string e.g. 3749 10 106 10690 10692 10693 10695 10658 10689. regarding to the original file, the "10" in that big string is at position 11 and 12. if you slice strings start is included, end excluded that is why line[:11] is from 0 to 10 and line[13:] is from 13 to the end

Comment: Oh ok. I got it. Thanks. I ran your without dataframes file with first part of code was for  inserting lines of magnet, iron and air. The values are getting changed but now the first part of code which is this oldLines[n:n] = [magnet, iron, air] not working. Can you add this first part of code in your without using dataframes code, so that entire answer will be in one place.

Comment: see my answer. i added a 3rd solution. it is the whole script and works fine with everything you wanted and the way you wrote your code

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks for all your inputs. I will also try with other files.

Comment: Hey @Rabinzel, can you explain this line list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == tmp_tryout[0], data_density)), I understood lambda filter is performing x[0] == tmp_tryout[0] operation on data_density but it takes data from data_density or tmp_tryout as both are from different files. I am confused in this line.

Comment: this line of code has the goal to get the index of the row where the ID of both files are matching, so that we can access that row (in data_density) with index 2 and 3 to check whether magnet/iron/air. tmp_tryout[0] is just the ID which is compared in that loop. density_idx_line is a list with exactly one row of data density. see the comment I wrote before that lambda line

Comment: Oh ok. I understood it now.

Comment: for other file, the problem is the lines which are inserted are dependent on collectors, here it was 17(you see 17 at start of tryout file after "BEG_COMP_DATA"), the lines then will be 18 for magnet.., so if the number of collectors are 10, then the lines will be  11, 12 & 13. Is there  a way to add like magnet = "      m+1"'"                      topo_magnet"'"\n" instead of magnet = "      18 "'"                      topo_magnet"'"\n"  where m will be based on the number of collectors, read this 17 as m & should change m accordingly like m+1, m+2 & m+3, so that it will not be hard coded.

Comment: in that case you can use f-string. instead of paste the line hard coded, you replace the 18/19/20 with {m+1}, {m+2}, {m+3} in the string. if that number after the row BEG_COMP_DATA always is the max number of collectors you can use that one as m, or you need to find the highest collector by coding.

Comment: I have managed to read the max number of collectors and also used the f string. Its working now. After adding the collectors, m changes from 17 to 20, this also needs to change in the file. So, the file will have new m 20 instead of 17.The code I have added is m = int(oldLines[3]) and then f strings for m+1...., so now m is int, How do I replace new_m to 20(not hardcoded) because replace method is for strings not for integers?

Comment: I tried to use m1 = str(m), new_m = m+3, new_m1 = str(new_m)and then under codeline with open(newFileName,"w") as newFile: newFile.write(oldLines[3].replace(m1, new_m1)). Its working separately but could not able to write it together with: with open(newFileName,"w") as newFile:
    newFile.write(oldLines[3].replace(m1, new_m1))
    new_file_contents = "".join(oldLines)   
    newFile.write(new_file_contents)

Comment: is the code still like here in the post ? As in the comments written this block of code with open(newFileName,"w") as newFile: .... is just for nothing because directly after that you create exactly the same file as a new one in mod "w" so you delete all the content and overwrite it. Why don't you just replace that 17 with 20 in the loop (for row in oldLines:......)? you could just do an if statement, if row[3]: newFile.write(row.replace(m1, new_m1))

Comment: I have edited your final 3rd solution code and put the changes accordingly which was working for me and also added the if row[3]: newFile.write(row.replace(m1, new_m1)) into this, its giving error as index is out of range. I have added this if statement after this code line in for loop: tmp_tryout = lst.split().

Comment: you still didn't understand it right. the context manager after the additional f-strings are a waste because directly after you open the file again in "w". you can just delete that, instead you deleted my comments to it :D

Comment: yes, you get the out of index error because you loop through every row, so at the moment you are at the row in third line (3rd loop) the row can't have index 3 (sorry I didn't thought about that either)

Comment: I can only repeat myself, it helped me a lot, especially in such data manipulations. Search in youtube for tutorials where they show you how to debug efficiently with spyder. then set some breakpoints and watch the variables, see what your code does and so on...... you would have seen that row[3] can't work at that point.

Comment: Ok. I will do the debugging in Spyder.

Comment: i change the code so that it works. two things: instead of "for row in oldLines" use enumerate, so you can access the index. and the other thing, that if condition needs to be at different place because otherwise he writes this row twice to the new file.

Comment: Yeah, it works like that. Now only hardcoded part is files at the top oldFileName = 'tryout.hmo' and so on. I was trying to create main function file which has these files and second file will only have rest of the code with function file that calls files into it. And with command parser, I want to run it directly. Am I in the correct direction?

Comment: Don't forget, I'm still also a beginner. I started to look into running scripts from the command line and I think what you want to achieve isn't that difficult, but I can't really help there.

Comment: are you on windows ?

Comment: I am using Linux. Ok. I will look into it.

Comment: ha i solved it! you don't have to change much. copy this to a text file and save it anywhere as "filename_you_want.sh": ```#!bin/bash
python path/to/your/file/main.py path/to/your/tryoutFile/Tryout.hmo path/to/your/NewOutputFile/tryout_NEW.hmo path/to/your/DensityFile/Density.topo

echo Script finished^!

read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key``` in your code in main.py you do import sys, then change the Filenames to OldFilename= sys.argv[1], NewFileName=sys.argv[2], topoFileName=sys.argv[3]

Comment: ah and in the main.py there is one line where we forgot to take the variable. Instead of "with open('Density.topo') as f:" you need to take the variable name "with open(topoFileName) as f

Answer (score 1):

I'm also still a beginner in Python, but I tried to solve your problem and here is my solution:

I guess there are way better ways to do it because here you have to import all data to a dataframe before comparing it.

Also I don't know if you can read your data with pd.read_csv to a dataframe because I don't know *.hmo and *.topo

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tryout.csv', delimiter=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv('density.csv', delimiter=';')

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for idx2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row[0] == row2[0]:
            if row2[2] == 1 and row2[3] == 0 :
                # it is magnet, value 18
                row[1] = 18
            elif row2[2] == 1 and row2[3] == 1 :
                # it is iron, value 19
                row[1] = 19
            else:
                # it is air, value 20
                row[1] = 20
df.to_csv('new_tryout.csv')
```

What my code is doing here, it loads both files to dataframes. Then iterate over every line to compare where the ID in both files is the same (e.g 3749).
If true there are the 3 if statements whether it is magnet/iron/air and change the value in df to the right number.

At the end save the new df to a new file 'new_tryout.csv'

I created 2 testfiles for it and it worked the way it should.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Its easy in dataframe but the main problem was the tryout file is difficult to convert to csv as it has different sizes of rows and columns which vary throughout the tryout file which I explained above and I am not sure that element column is row[0] which is first column(it would be if it was in dataframe but not here I guess) thats why I was trying with python and changes from 10 to 18 or 19 or 20 is needed only in BEG_ELEM_DATA in tryout file. If you want I can share my file but there is no option here for sharing, is there?

Comment: do you know if the BEG_ELEM_DATA has the same size of columns? Then you could skip all the rows before the start of BEG_ELEM_DATA and then reading it in as suggested

Comment: I tried the usual way to convert using pd.read_csv(r'path\file name.txt) and then to_csv method but the problem is that the values are not in separated columns rather: for density file- all values in one column like 3749  10 1.0  0.0  and for tryout file also all values in column. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't know if there is a direct way to share the data. You can upload it somewhere and copy the link here.

Comment: you just need to set the delimiter to tab (delimiter='\t') if I understand it right

Comment: Do you need to have the tryout.hmo file where the values of 10 are changed to 18/19/20 or could you also have a csv file at the end with just the BEG_ELEM_DATA?

Comment: I need the entire tryout.hmo file with the values of 10 changed to 18/19/20, if possible in same format in .hmo for further use.

Comment: I couldn't do it. I need to change the format of that .hmo file to get access to it and to compare the data, so after I changed the values the format is different and that's not what you want. Maybe someone else with more experience finds a way.

Comment: btw if you after all want to read it in as DataFrame, you can use this: `df = pd.read_csv('tryout.hmo', header = None, delimiter=r'\s+', skiprows=[i for i in range(52363)])` and `df2 = pd.read_csv('Density.topo', header= None, delimiter=r'\s+', skiprows=2)`

Comment: Yeah ok. I also changed the .hmo format extension to .txt and then converted into CSV file. So with your code, if I get CSV file with changed values, then we can again convert back to .txt file right?

Comment: you don't even need to convert it to csv. *.txt is also fine and works with that pd.read_csv

Comment: Also, in the first line where you are reading the df from tryout.hmo file, then after changing the values, it will not write those values and save it in the last line as df is opened for reading not writing right?

Comment: the data of tryout is stored in df and df doesn't need the file after read_csv. All the data is now in python. I change the df in my script and at the end I write the whole df into a new file called new_tryout

Comment: I have tried today with your code but there is no CSV file new_tryout is getting saved in my folder. It only shows running in Spyder.  I read that iterating over using df.iterrows is slow.Did it work for you with the files I shared because data is huge?

Comment: iterrows is so slow. Didn't know how slow it is for such big files. That seems not to be a propper solution. A better way to do this is df.apply() with map and lambda function. But I couldn't figure out how to write a lambda function for your if/else statement to decide whether 18/19/20. I'd really like to see someone more experienced in Python would answer to your post and how he would solve it.

Comment: I was trying with df.itertuples but could not figure out. Can someone more experienced help? Should I change the question?

Comment: I will try itertuples tomorrow and see, if it fast enough to work...

Comment: change question maybe good, but what would you change ? Split your problems into smaller bits maybe? I don't know how to get the attention of some experts :D

Comment: Yeah, do tell me if you could solve with itertuples. Also, I ran the code for around4 hours, got the file but the new_tryout file is merged of 2 files: Section of BEG_ELEM_DATA from tryout file and entire density file is merged.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is another solution. For anybody else who reads this: this is still only a temporary solution but @Sagar and me both don't know to do it better.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('tryout.hmo', header = 0, names = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLM'), delimiter=r'\s+', skiprows=[i for i in range(52362)])
df2 = pd.read_csv('Density.topo', header = 0, names = list('ANOP'), delimiter=r'\s+', skiprows=1)
df2 = df2.iloc[:-3, :]

df3 = df.merge(df2, how='outer', on='A')
df3[['O','P']] = df3[['O','P']].fillna(-1).astype(int).replace(-1, np.nan)

df3['B']= df3.apply(lambda x: 18 if x['B']==10 and x['O']==1 and x['P']==0 else (
    19 if x['B']==10 and x['O']==1 and x['P']==1 else (
    20 if x['B']==10 and x['O']==0 and x['P']==0 else x['B'])), axis=1)

df3.to_csv('new_tryout.csv')
```

It finished the code in less than a second, so it is far better than iterrows or itertuples.
The new csv file includes both the tryout file and the density file. They are merged together by the first column of tryout file (ID i guess)

I didn't check all of this very big file but from the few random points I checked, it seems as this way works.

Comment: I checked it but if you check element such as 3749 or any element who has value 10 in tryout file is not changed, also the file is not correctly merged. Its difficult to work with merged file as I wanted it in same tryout file with changed values.

Comment: yes, the tryout file didn't change at all. It is about the new_tryout file, and I just checked 3749. It has the value 18 as it should be. Before saving it as the new_tryout file you could delete the last 3 columns so you only have the original columns of tryout, no big of a deal

Comment: Yeah, I meant in the new_tryout file, the 3749 line is as follows: 2765,3749,10.0,106.0,10690.0,10692.0,10693.0,10695.0,10658.0,10689.0,,,,,2,1.0,0.0., so the value of 10 is not changed in my csv then. Also, the new_tryout file, as you said, last three columns and 1st column needs to be deleted and also add the rest part of tryout file then it will be the tryout file with changed values. This becomes I guess even more complicated right, what you think?

Comment: Weird. Did you copy paste my code exactly like I posted it ? Maybe you have different python version. To the 2nd part of your question: deleting the columns is easy. Adding the first part of the tryout file could be a bit tricky because of the inconsistent columns. I'll try. It is always good practise for me though.

Comment: I am using 3.9.5 python version.